# Why does google keep deleting URLs from https in search console

Tags: seo, google-search, search-engine-indexing, search-engines

Google search console has HTTPS section that I understand shows urls those are served over https.  My whole site is https. I have noticed that  when a new ad is created, that url shows up under https section but after a few days google drops it from https section.  When I inspect that URL, it looks fine. Google "Test Live URL"  shows no problem and it is shown as indexed, available on mobile, Served over https and a valid breadcrumb

So why is it being removed from https section ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That report only includes examples of pages. i.e. it is a sample of all your https pages. So nothing to worry about if it does not list a specific page you are interested in.

Comment: It has a graph that shows how many https URLs were there on a given day.  It also has a red box Non-Https URLs and a green box for  Https URLs.  Are these numbers also the numbers related to the sample ?   I understand that clicking on the link "View examples of HTTPS pages"  shows just a few samples.   However I would think that Green box with number of HTTPS urls would be the total number of HTTPS urls on the site.

Comment: I checked a few properties. It looks like the HTTPS totals equal the number of examples and not the number of indexed pages. I'd not worry about this report unless you are seeing red HTTP examples.